# Prove that $ x= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\varepsilon_k}{3^k}$

Tags: analysis, induction, cauchy-sequences, p-adic-number-theory

How can I prove that all number $ x\in  \mathbb{R}:0 <|x|\leq \frac{1}{2}$  is possible to write as:

$$ x= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\varepsilon_k}{3^k} $$
$$\varepsilon_k \in \{-1,0, 1\} \, \forall \,k \in \mathbb{N}$$

There is any relationship with [p-adic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)? wehre $x = \frac{a}{b} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kp^{-k}$

I'm not sure how the problem to treat...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No real relation to the $3$-adic numbers, ’cause these are written $\sum a_kp^k$ ( positive exponents not negative ! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $\epsilon_k\in\{0,1,2\}$ instead, you'd have teh base-3 expansion of an arbitrary number $\in[0,1]$ on the right (with allowing the 3-ary equivalent of $0.9999\ldots =1$). But we need $\{-1,0,1\}$, so we substract $\sum_k \frac1{3^k}$ and that happens to be $\frac12$. Thus we turn the interval of  representable numbers $[0,1]$ into the interval $[-\frac12,\frac12]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!. I've got one more question.. when $x = \frac{1}{7} $ how can I find the $\varepsilon_k$?